# How to Integrate/use Camunda BPMN Model API in ReactJs frontend to edit bpmn diagrams?

Tags: reactjs, bpmn, camunda

I am working on a React-Python/Flask app which takes input bpmn diagram image from user & through python scripts convert it into bpmn file which then can be downloaded through flask api on user's device. I am working on react UI. Now i have to edit the diagrams & apply some visualization to them. So how can i use Camunda BPMN Model API in my app.I am new to Camunda & i have gone through Camunda with React docs but i am still confused on where or how to start. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand you correctly: With *input bpmn diagram image* you do refer to a picture (with pixels), and not to the BPMN-XML-file, right? So you need to do [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)? If so, you might want to add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: Yes I refered to a Picture with Pixals But i have the Needed python scripts to change them into .bpmn file. Now here i need Camunda APIs to edit this .bpmn file. So no i dont have to tag OCR because i am already converted the image to bpmn.

Answer (score 2):

I am not professional in Camunda BPMN, but I am doing now research about it. Are you looking for bpmn.js library? Here is an example for BPMN Modeler:
https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/modeler

And this is how you can integrate the library with React, basically, all you need is to provide ref from React.

```
const containerRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   const bpmnViewer = new BpmnJS({ container: containerRef.current });
}, []);
```

JSX Template:

```
<div ref={containerRef}></div>
```

Example here:
https://github.com/bpmn-io/react-bpmn/blob/master/src/index.jsx#L25

Comment: Thank You for your help But no I have tried bpmn.js but it does not fulfill the requirements of my app. That's why i am looking into Camunda BPMN APIs.